Configuring eslint-parser with custom babel plugin so that VS code intellisense works
I am trying to do the following (i am in learning stage):
I made a simple babel plugin which looks for a variable declaration const magic = { ... } and inserts a property as follows: const magic = { word : 'abracadabra', ... }
My plugin is as follows:
// plugin-learn.cjs
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      VariableDeclarator(path) {
        if (t.isIdentifier(path.node.id, { name: "magic" })) {
          console.log("found magic...");
          path
            .get("init")
            .unshiftContainer(
              "properties",
              t.objectProperty(
                t.identifier("word"),
                t.stringLiteral("abracadabra")
              )
            );
        }
      },
    },
  };
};


Which upon running babel cli npx babel index.js --out-dir dist works as intended.
// babel.config.json
{
  "plugins": ["./plugin-learn.cjs"]
}


// index.js (original)
const magic = {number: 777};



// dist/index.js
const magic = {word: 'abracadabra', number: 777};


My Question is: How to make VS Code intellisense work on the transformed code?
Things I tried (1)
After searching I came to understand that eslint with a custom parser (eslint-parser) is needed, and we must disable the builtin VS code javascript validator. So I configured eslint as follows:

// eslint.config.js
import babelParser from "@babel/eslint-parser";
import globals from "globals";
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parser: babelParser,
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
      },
    },
  },
];


VS Code ESLint settings is as follows:
// settings.json (VS code workspace settings file)
{
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript"],
  "eslint.debug": true,
  "eslint.enable": true,
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "eslint.useFlatConfig": true
}


But it doesn't work. I tried different variations of the config files .cjs, .mjs, .json; passing babel options via eslint.config.js instead of using the default one, disabling useFlatConfig in VS code settings, all to no avail.
Things I tried (2)
2nd variation of what I tried: From the seemingly related question: Declaring babel plugins for @babel/eslint-parser in .eslintrc
// eslint.config.js
...
   parser: babelParser,
   parserOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: false,
        babelOptions: {
          babelrc: false,
          configFile: false,
          // your babel options
          plugins: ["./plugin-learn.cjs"],
        },
      },

Things I tried (3)
3rd variation of what I tried:
// eslint.config.js

const customParser = {
  parse(code, options) {
    const ast = babelParser.parse(code, options);
    /* 
       modifying the ast using babel traverse
    */
  }
};

export default [
  ...
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parser: customParser,
    }
  ...
  },
];


VS Code intellisense still didn't work.
May I kindly know where am I going wrong. Does VS Code intellisense actually work this way or am I completely wrong? Also I would appreciate some pointers to learn as well.
Thanks...
PS: VS code ESLint extension is operational, as I can see some logs in the "Output" panel...
PS: my package.json file
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.25.1",
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "globals": "^15.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.25.6"
  }
}


